# How do you unsubscribe from a Svelte store in a module context?

Tags: javascript, module, components, svelte, store

I have the following module:

```
<script lang="ts" context="module">
  import type { Config } from './types'
  import {
    config,
    // ... several more here
  } from './stores'

  let config_value: Config 
  config.subscribe(value => {
    config_value = value
  })
</script>
```

But, according to the [docs](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions):

> The app in the previous example works, but there's a subtle bug — the store is subscribed to, but never unsubscribed. If the component was instantiated and destroyed many times, this would result in a memory leak.

However, since this is `context="module"`, when trying to run an `onDestroy` method, it produces the following error:

> Function called outside component initialization

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Does this apparent memory leak apply to modules, or only to components?
2. If so, how do I unsubscribe from these stores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this apparent memory leak apply to modules, or only to components?

Kind of, there should only be one instance of the module loaded, so this should only add one listener, rather than one per component, which could potentially cause issues if there are many. As there is no accumulation over time, this could be considered to be not a leak.

> If so, how do I unsubscribe from these stores?

Modules generally do not unload and even if they do, there isn't any event for it that could be subscribed to. You could count component instances and subscribe when the first is created and unsubscribe when the last is destroyed.

The real question is, why are you doing this in the first place?

`context=module` is *not* something one should need to use often if at all. There is nothing in your example code that would justify using it.